# php Overwrite method and call the overwritten

Tags: php, class, methods, overwrite

I know this can be avoided with just using another method name but I was curious as to if the following was possible.

I have this class: ( of course it has some more methods but they aren't relevant to the question )

```
class db extends mysqli {
    public function query($sql){
        $sql = $this->parent->query($sql);

        if($this->error){
            echo "<script>popup('SQL error bro!');</script>";
        }else{
            return $sql;
        }
    }
}
```

What I wanna do is call the original mysqli query() method from within the query() method I created. Is it possible or I shall get started renaming?

And also I'd like to point out that this is purely for development use, I know users aren't supposed to see sql errors. Reason I want to do this is that today I needed to change a table column name from id to vid, then my whole system stopped working and I spent 30 minutes researching, I'd just like to prevent that in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$this->parent->query($sql);
```

To

```
$sql = parent::query($sql);
```

Comment: For some reason neither of those syntaxes throws an error but neither one echoes that little script when I purposely provoke an error as well. O.o

Comment: The problem was a silly one as usual. This class is singleton and in the getInstance method I was calling new mysqli not new db. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Possible but might not be best practices:

```
parent::query($sql)
```

Comment: Why do you recon it might not be best practices?

Comment: I don't recon, but some folks would complain that :: looks like you're calling a static method and you're not.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the method of the superclass by calling

```
parent::query();
```

See also:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php